Why can't choked flow accelerate?
Why can't flow accelerate in the choked condition?
I think the best way to explain my question is through an example, so here it is:

Imagine you have $2$ boxes connected with a valve that is closed. One box has zero air molecules (total vacuum), and the other has very high pressure air. When you open this valve, the air molecules now 'see' this empty space that they can accelerate into, so they do just that.
Now, picture this same scenario but with the air molecules moving through the valve at M = $1$. (choked flow)
When they're at this speed, what mechanism is stopping the molecules from accelerating further?

I've seen explanations that say it's because pressure disturbances and information can't travel upstream when the flow is at M = $1$ but this is kind of confusing (and this brings up the thing I'm most confused about), because:
If the area downstream of the choked flow is a complete vacuum, what is stopping the upstream choked-molecules from 'feeling' the lack of pressure downstream, and therefore accelerating?
In this case, it wouldn't matter if the downstream flow could communicate to the upstream flow, I don't think.

Well, the fact that the flow is choked - the outlet is not large enough to let all the molecules through that want to go through. If you try to empty a stadium through one tunnel, you can only get so many people through the tunnel at a time, regardless of how many there are still in the stadium. At the exit of the tunnel, people don't feel any 'force' from those remaining in the stadium.

@JonCuster Thanks for the insight. Perhaps I wasn't taking into account the density of the flow itself and was focusing solely on the pressures. However, if there is some sort of force 'pulling' the people out of the tunnel faster, wouldn't the flow of people also move faster?

The main reason is that the impetus for flow (as commonly understood) comes from fluid (as conventionally understood) in a high pressure state (rather than a low pressure state), and in order for "pressure" (as conventionally understood) to be well defined, the fluid needs to be sufficiently near thermal equilibrium that unit cells can be defined with near uniform (i.e. approximately non-random) bulk properties. However, if the fluid is near thermal equilibrium, or near enough that something like "pressure" is well-defined, individual particles (the microscopic constituents of the fluid) will move around randomly and collide with each other with some mean-free-path $\ell$ that is much smaller than the "unit cell" on which the gas exhibits fluid-like properties. This is far from obvious (unless you take the laws of thermodynamics for granted), but it turns out that in weakly interacting gases (e.g. hard sphere or Lennard-Jones gases) sound propagates isentropically rather than, say, isothermally.  What this means is that unit cells in gases are far better insulated from their neighbors than one might expect, at least at normal pressures and length scales over which sound can propagate (in extremely dilute gases, you need to worry about whether the mean free path is comparable to, e.g., the channel length or box dimensions.)  As soon as pressure builds to a point where the mean free path is substantially less than the relevant length scales, particles (or more precisely, unit cells) will tend to "jam" in aggregate, and it will be effectively impossible for impulses in the high pressure region to propagate faster than sound (at least absent an egregious disturbance from equilibrium.) Basically, if you try to sustain (substantively) supersonic flow in steady state, you will effectively transform the erstwhile gas into a non-equilibrium semi-condensed phase with completely different physics from what you started with.  This is not to say that you cannot achieve dilute flow with speeds exceeding $v_s$ in a channel: just that the channel width would need to be large relative to the momentum diffusion length-scale, and you would need to increase the flow rate gradually rather than "all at once."  Also, in the transient phase of choke flow interesting phenomena can take place at the 'interface' or boundary layer between an expanding locally-equilibrated gas and a vacuum.

I'm not sure I fully understand. Are you saying the spacing of the molecules prevents them from accelerating at Mach 1? I apologize if I'm misunderstanding.

I'm saying that the particles in the "high pressure region" have to collide with each other in order for "pressure" to be well-defined (i.e. non-zero in the thermodynamic limit), and as a result they cause the fluid to 'jam' at subsonic local speeds.
